# certwatch NSS_Init failure

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate

Ever since I set up my CentOS 6 web server and created my own certificates, daily cron has been sending an email to root:

```
/etc/cron.daily/certwatch:

NSS_Init("/etc/pki/nssdb") failed
```

I found /etc/cron.daily/certwatch which scans httpd.conf and tries to validate certificates.  When I run `certwatch` on the command line I see the same error message:

```
# certwatch /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt 
NSS_Init("/etc/pki/nssdb") failed
```

What does this `NSS_Init` error message mean, and (if I can get past this error) can `certwatch` check if certificates I created expire?